# What is the correct way to get a compound value

Tags: java, class

I'm working in a project where there is a relation among 3 classes: Collection, Serie and Card.

A collection has id and name.
A serie has id and name.
A card has id and name.

A collection is compound of 20 series.
A serie is compound 20 cards.

So, I have a relationship that I think I can solve in this way:

```java
class Collection {
    final String id;
    final String name;
    final List<Serie> series;

    public Collection(String id, String name, List<Serie> series) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.series = series;
    }
}

class Serie {
    final String id;
    final String name;
    final List<Card> cards;

    public Serie(String id, String name, List<Card> cards) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cards = cards;
    }
}

class Card {
    final String id;
    final String name;

    public Card(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The thing is that I have to show a layout where the card has to show the name and a compound value that is form in this way: collection id + serie name + card id.

Should I add an extra attribute to Card that hold that value? Or what do you think that could be a good way to go?

Comment: You shouldn't pollute your data model with display values. If your UI wants properties from different objects, pass all those objects to the relevant UI and solve it there.

Comment: Or I suppose you could make a temporary value when it's needed, like a String, and pass that to the UI.

Comment: Or, if the view is particularly complex, create a view object. This can also help extract view-related logic—views themselves should be thin.

Comment: I thought that is very redundant sent collection, serie and card to card detail view to only show a compound attribute. In my opinion, I should only pass card, but I don't know what is the best way to deal with the problem of compound value. I will check your comments and try your solutions! Thank you.

Comment: `Collection` is an interface from `java.util`, I would recommend to choose a different name to avoid confusion (unrelated to your issue, but good to know)

Comment: FWIW you may want to look at the Presenter or Decorator patterns *(with the caveat that the definitions and names of what could be used here vary wildly)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I add an extra attribute to Card that hold that value? Or what do you think that could be a good way to go?

There is no absolute answer here. Context matters.

As noted in the Comments, generally it is best to keep arbitrary presentation separate from content ("model"). But not if the desired presentation text is intrinsic to the entity represented by the data model.

- If the presentation details could reasonably vary for various reasons, then your data model (the three classes you showed us) should *not* generate that particular value. Presentation text should be generated by some other class, not your data model classes (`Collection`, `Serie`, `Card`). For example, in the *java.time* classes, see the `DateTimeFormatter` class that generates arbitrary or complex text on behalf of the date-time classes such as `LocalDate`.
- If that particular presentation text (collection id + serie name + card id) is canonical or standardized as a formal/official structure, then your data model classes (`Collection`, `Serie`, `Card`) *should* generate that text. For example, the *java.time* classes have a `toString` class that generates text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, as well as a [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) method to generate formatted text.

So we cannot really answer your particular question, because we do not have an understanding of the domain from which you get your collection, serie, and card entities.

---

By the way, we can simplify that code.

If your classes are meant primarily to be transparent carriers of shallowly-immutable data, then use [`record`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) in Java 16+. The constructor, getters, `hashCode` & `equals`, and `toString` are all implicitly created by the compiler.

In Java 21+, you can use the more general interface `SequencedCollection` interface rather than `List`. See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

As mentioned it Comments, `Collection` is the super-interface of the classes found in the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework). I would choose a different name if at all possible. If intrinsic to your domain, then just be careful with your `import` statements.

Your Question’s code then becomes:

```java
class Collection ( String id , String name , SequencedCollection < Serie > series ) {}
```

```java
class Serie ( String id , String name , SequencedCollection < Card > cards ) {}
```

```java
class Card ( String id , String name ) {}
```

You can add additional methods to a record. If you decide your presentation text is intrinsic to your model, add a method named something like `getDisplayName`.

```java
class Collection ( String id , String name , SequencedCollection < Serie > series ) 
{
    public String getDisplayName() 
    { 
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder() ;
        for ( Serie serie : this.series ) 
        { 
            for ( Card card : serie.cards )
            {
                stringBuilder
                    .append( this.id ) 
                    .append( " | " ) 
                    .append( serie.name ) 
                    .append( " | " ) 
                    .append( card.id ) 
                    .append( "\n" ) 
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. It's very helpful. The only thing is that getDisplayName should be a method hold on by Card no Collection, since I want to construct this compound name only with a object of type card. Anyway, your response is very useful ^^.